# EU Gmail substitute

Tags: email, webapp-rec

I want a web-based e-mail service which

1. displays e-mails sorted by conversation;
2. can import e-mails from POP3 accounts;
3. can send e-mails from other accounts (either by faking the `From`
   header or by logging into that account's SMTP server);
4. is hosted in a location which is subject to the EU Data Protection
   Act;
5. is not subject to the US PATRIOT Act (hence, not run by an EU
   subsidiary of a US company);
6. provides a large amount of storage space.

I do have a shared hosting account in the UK, so if there's any FOSS software I could install there, that'd be good, but I'm mainly looking for a service provider to handle it for me.

Comment: This might be useful as a starting point - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_webmail_providers

Comment: This is another possible resource: http://alternativeto.net/software/gmail/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fastmail.fm/

Originally an Australian company. Now owned by Opera (norwegian company) since 2010. **Norway is not part of EU.**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastMail.FM

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Software

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norway

Comment: But their servers are US based: `We are located in Melbourne Australia, we use IBM servers hosted by NYI in NYC US. FastMail.FM is now run by Opera Software Australia Pty Ltd, a whole owned subsidiary of Opera Software ASA of Norway.` From their [help page](http://www.fastmail.fm/help/overview_company_info.html). And it's an Australian company, even if it's owned by a Norwegian one.

Comment: @Alex: ok sorry I didn't see that.